# ambethia / recaptch doesn't work with Rails 4 (Ruby 2.1.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, recaptcha

I've installed this gem [ambethia/recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha)
as described in the Readme.md file. Restarted the server after setting up the configure and the public keys.

My problem... Captcha just can't get trough. Here's what I'm doing:

In the gemfile: 
gem "recaptcha", :require => "recaptcha/rails"

In my view:

```
...form stuff generally...
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

In my controller:

```
def create
  @form = Form.new(form_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if verify_recaptcha(:model => @form, :message => t(:wrong_captcha)) && @form.save
            format.html do 
                FormMailer.application_email(@form).deliver
                flash[:success] = t(:form_success)
                format.html { redirect_to root_path }
            end
        else
            format.html { render 'new' }
        end
    end
end
```

Regardless of the fact all seems ok (as far as I could tell from carefully reading the instructions in the gem readme file), I can't submit the form. It continuously shows error message that the Captcha code was wrong.

And on top of all, after I've installed this gem, an awful flash message saying "HTML" is showing in the form page when you submit it.

I have read the bug reports in the gem, but nothing about such an issue. Please, help me.

Best Regards,
Sly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Turbolinks, you will need to do

```
<%= recaptcha_tags(ajax: true) %>
```

instead of just

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
```